# How hide symbolic definition of a function?

Tags: functions, security

How can the actual definition of a function be hidden from a user?

I want the user of a notebook to be able to evaluate a real-valued function f of a real variable at any particular numeric input yet not be able to see the symbolic expression that defines it. E.g.:

```
f[x_]:=Exp[-x] Cos[2x]
```

Of course I know I want to hide the definition of `f` in a package, say `func.m` consisting of something like the following:

```
BeginPackage["func`"]
f::usage = "f[x] gives the value of the secret function f at x";

Begin["`Private`"]
f[x_]:=Exp[-x] Cos[2x]
SetAttributes[f,{ReadProtected,Locked}]
End[]

EndPackage[]
```

This package file would be `Encode`d and put into the same directory as a notebook, say `work.nb` where the user will work with the hidden definition. And this notebook would include, in an Initialization cell:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Get["func`"]
```

But after that cell is evaluated, still evaluating

```
f[x]
```

unfortunately reveals the symbolic definition of `f`.

Is it possible somehow to hide the symbolic definition yet be able to evaluate `f` at arbitrary numeric input?

Comment: Hmm... does it really show up even in a fresh mma session? Are you sure that you're loading the encoded file and not the plain text .m file (I think just ``Get["func`"]`` will load the m file)? I haven't tried it yet since I don't have a free kernel right now, but it seems like what you're suggesting should work...

Comment: Ohh... never mind. I see what your problem is. Just define `f` as `f[x_?NumericQ]` and that should fix it.

Comment: @rm -rf: Yes, I just realized that's the way. For the record, please make that an answer.  Or at least its part of the way. Clearly I need to take an additional step lest the more clever use try something like `f[Pi]` and begin to get a hint of the definition. Namely, use `f[x_?NumericQ] := N[Exp[-x] Cos[2x]`.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can just use `_?NumberQ`. I will make that an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're suggesting seems fine to me. The only additional step necessary is to restrict the definition of `f` to only numeric values (i.e., keep it unevaluated for symbolic input). The way to do that would be to use the pattern test `NumericQ` on the input as:

```
Clear@f
f[x_?NumericQ] := Exp[-x] Cos[2 x]
```

which will not evaluate for input such as `f[x]`. However, as you note, it will evaluate for symbolic forms of numerical values, such as `Pi`, `E`, `GoldenRatio`, etc., which can give the user a hint to the underlying form:

```
f /@ {E, Pi, GoldenRatio}
(* {E^-E Cos[2 E], E^-Pi, E^-GoldenRatio Cos[2 GoldenRatio]} *)
```

There are two solutions here:

- If you want to provide a numerical output, you could just apply `N` on the RHS in the definition

  ```
  Clear@f
  f[x_?NumericQ] := N[Exp[-x] Cos[2 x]]

  f /@ {E, Pi, GoldenRatio}
  (* {0.0437182, 0.0432139, -0.197404} *)
  ```
- If you want to keep it unevaluated, you could use [`NumberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberQ.html) to restrict the pattern:

  ```
  Clear@f
  f[x_?NumberQ] := Exp[-x] Cos[2 x]

  f /@ {E, Pi, GoldenRatio}
  (* {f[E], f[Pi], f[GoldenRatio]} *)
  ```

---

If your user is smart enough, they can still work around this by tricking `f` to believe that a symbol `x` is also a numeric value (example using the `NumericQ` definition of `f`):

```
NumericQ[x] = True;
f[x]
(* 2.71828^(-1. x) Cos[2. x] *)
```

You can do the same with `NumberQ` after unprotecting it. To avoid this, you can include a dummy definition for `_Symbol`:

```
f[x_Symbol] := Null
```

Comment: -f: Yes, I already noted I'll want to wrap with N so as to hinder "decoding" the function by plugging in symbolic numerical entities such as Pi.

Comment: @murray Please also see my update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the ploy `f[x_Symbol] := Null` works to avoid the `NumericQ[x] = True` attack. When I do that and then evaluate `f[x]` I obtain result `2.71828^(1. x) Cos[2. x]`.

Comment: @murray Ah, I wasn't explicit — the definition for `_Symbol` should come before that for `_?NumericQ`. It won't work if you place it after.

Comment: I wondered about the order. I knew that "general" rules are applied only after "particular case" rules, but I hadn't recalled seeing an explicit statement that otherwise it's the order that counts.I find it now, in the final paragraph of the exposition in `tutorial/TheOrderingOf Definitions`: "Whenever the appropriate ordering is not clear, Mathematica stores rules in the order you give them."

Comment: I think we're going to have to be even more clever to prevent attack at the hidden definition, e.g., by the user trying `f[x+1]`. Adding a condition `FreeQ[x, _Symbol]` should do it.

Comment: Oops! Adding the condition `FreeQ[x, _Symbol]` won't help, because that would prevent accepting legitimate argument `Pi`, for example.

Comment: @murray Wouldn't a simple `f[_] := Null` suffice (after the other definitions)?

Comment: Yes, adding `f[_]:=Null` suffices. Actually, it's probably a good idea to return some message instead of `Null` for both `f[x_Symbol]` and `f[_]` lest the user think he failed to evaluate the cell and just tries again, futilely.

Comment: Note: These methods work to similarly protect "secret" definitions of functions whose arguments should be numeric vectors or matrices.